# How to compare newest commit to oldest commit in gitk

Tags: gitk

When I do `gitk --follow <filename>`, the left pane lists all the commits of the given filename.

If I click one of those commits, the bottom-left pane (just below the commit/branch/tag list), shows a `diff` between this selected commit and the previous one.

Is there a way to tell gitk to show a `diff` between this selected commit and the **oldest** commit? (i.e. the one at the bottom of the list)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select the new commit, then right-click the old commit (without selecting it first) and choose "Diff this -> selected".

Comment: Thanks +1. Is there a gitk manual or at least a short reference of these commands/operations somewhere?

Comment: This takes the cherry for non-intuitive UI.